# C++ Overloaded function not being called with string parameter

Tags: c++, overloading

I overloaded a function like the following:

```
void myClass::saveAsMat (bool complete){
  ...
}

void myClass::saveAsMat (std::string filename){
  ...
}
```

In my main.cpp when I call the function like this:

```
myObj.saveAsMat(true);
```

everthing works fine. But when I instead call the function like this:

```
myObj.saveAsMat("myName");
```

the function is not being executed at all. I expected a compile or runtime error but there is nothing like that. The program gets compiled and runs only that the function is ignored. (I checked this by placing some `std::cout` inside the function).

Then I found out that I can solve this by changing the argument passed to:

```
myObj.saveAsMat(string("myName"));
```

Why do I have to set the extra `string()` for the argument? Other functions that are not overloaded are working fine by simply passing `"myName"` for a `"std::string"` paramenter.

Comment: Conversion from `char*` to `bool` is a standard conversion; conversion to `std::string` is a user-defined conversion. The former is preferred in overload resolution. `myObj.saveAsMat("myName");` should be calling `myObj.saveAsMat(true);`